# Update database with date format

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sqlconnection

I found some threads here in the forum related to this problem but they didn't help me. I just want to update my database with a date value. These come from a Textfile (written there as 2014-10-02 for example). Now I tried this (which was mentioned in the other threads):

```
 String connectionQuery = form1.conString.Text;
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionQuery);
                SqlCommand sqlComInsert = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [" + form1.tableName.Text + "] ([" + form1.CusId.Text + "],["+ form1.date.Text +"],[" + form1.cusName.Text + "]) VALUES('" + cusId[i] + "',convert(date,'" + date[i] + "',104),'" + "','" + cusName[i] + "')", connection);

  sqlComInsert.Connection.Open();
                sqlComInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlComInsert.Connection.Close();
```

Now when I leave the "'" out ("',convert / "',104)) he tells me that the syntax is incorrect near 2013 (the beginning of my date). When I write it like above then I get:
String or binary data would be truncated.

What is this? I tried also to convert the date with:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < typeDelDate.Count; i++)
            {
                unFormatedDate = date[i];
                formatedDate = unFormatedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                dateFormat.Add(formatedDate);
            }
```

but I get still the same errors. How can I update my values? the column type is "date".

Comment: All of the answers say you should *NOT* use raw strings or string concatenations but pass date-typed parameters to parameterized queries. Your code does the opposite. Also note that you are passing other string values as well. If one of them is longer than the underlying field, you'll get a truncation warning.

Comment: I tried it now with the parameterized queries but I get the error I mentioned

Comment: As the messages says, you are trying to store a string to a field that is too short. This doesn't mean that the parameterized query is wrong, it means you need to either change the size of the field or truncate the string you are trying to save. Check the size of the strings you are trying to save and the size of the fields.

Answer (score 1):

Use parametrized queries instead of slapping strings together:

```
var commandText = "insert (column) values (@dt);";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dt", DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd"));

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Do not pass values into queries by adding strings - if possible, you should always use parameters. It saves you a lot of trouble converting to proper values (different for different locales etc.), it's more secure, and it helps performance.

Comment: How would that look in my case? When I concatenate strings? It would be too much work to rewrite everything

Comment: @ScorpX Leave everything the same, *except* for the `values` clause - there, you'll just have something like `(@customerId, @date, @customerName)`. And you add one parameter after another using the `Parameters.AddWithValue` as outlined above.

Comment: What is dateString? I have my date saved as DateTime

Comment: @ScorpX All the easier, just pass the `DateTime` value directly. I assumed you were parsing the value from a string first.

Comment: ("date", DateTime.ParseExact(date[i], "yyyy-MM-dd")); - He tells me it is overloaded

Comment: @ScorpX It tells you there's no overload of `ParseExact` taking `DateTime` and `string`. Just do `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", date[i]);`. Come on, this is basic C#.

Comment: Wow that worked with the normal AddParameter. Thank you very much! I'm very new to C# and still learning :)