# truncated datetime Exception in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sqlconnection

I have a problem in SQL and don't know why this is happening. First I show my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dateList.Count;i++ )
{
     String connectionQuery = form1.conStringBox.Text;
     SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionQuery);

     SqlCommand sqlComInsert = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [" + form1.tableName.Text + "] ([" + form1.cusName.Text + "],[" + form1.date.Text + "]) VALUES(@cusName, @date)", connection);
     sqlComInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("cusName", cusName[i]);
     sqlComInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("date",date[i]);
```

This modified code came from here:
[Update database with date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29212664/update-database-with-date-format)

I try to describe the most important things:
I have a textfile where I read the values from (there are two columns -> `cusName` and `date`). I store them in two lists (`cusName list = String`, `date list = DateTime`). Now I want to store them in my database. The columntype of the date column is datetime.

Somehow with the above code I get an exception (`string or binary data would be truncated`). This happens at the date column. In my SQL Server 2008 it get's displayed as (for example) `2013-10-21 00:00:00.000`. Since I'm working on a german computer, when I put them in my List they get displayed as: `21.10.2013 00:00:00`.

Now why do I have accepted the answer in the other thread? Because when I tried the above code on another computer it worked. When I'm trying this on the computer I'm sitting right now I get the error. I'm working with SQL Server 2008 and Windows 7 on both computers (but I once realized that there are differences with the case sensivity on SQL Server). So I don't know where the error is. Hope someone can help me.

Sample data from a textfile looks like for every row:

Name1;2013-09-27

Comment: Have you tried to load text file using OleDb? Please, provide sample data.

Comment: loading the textfile shouldn't be the problem. It gets read and the values get stored into Lists. That works. I don't want to use OleDb.

Comment: Your problem is perhaps not the datetime column but the lenght of varchar column. Try to check if the strings inserted are longer then your varchar column length.

Comment: No. both are german computers. Both have Windows 7 running on them and both use SQL Server 2008. So I don't know where the problem is. I check the char columns...

Comment: Ok thanks for the hint. I realized that in this database a char column had the size "3" while the string I tried to add had length "4". What a silly mistake. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend formatting the date strings in YYYYMMDD format before sending them to the SQL server.

I would assume that passing a DateTime-typed field would handle the conversion automatically, but I haven't worked with servers/computers in different regions, so I don't know that for sure.  I do know that SQL will handle converting a "YYYYMMDD" string into a Date/DateTime (continue passing the string as a parameter if you go that route).

On the other hand, the error that you mentioned is not commonly associated with DateTime fields (they will usually give you something about a date conversion failure).  I would double-check your name column and the lengths of all of your name inputs, just in case.  Could also be multi-byte encoding on the strings that makes them take up more room than they appear to?  It's hard to say without knowing what the input looks like!

Comment: Yes. It was a problem in the char length of one certain column. SQL seems to convert the dates automatically when you use the parameter input.

Comment: Ah, good to know!  I spent too long typing and didn't see the comments earlier!